# Wrap Data into Object form

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a dataset like this:

```
[ { city: 'a', value: 1, sector: 'Hospital' },
  { city: 'b', value: 1, sector: 'Hardware' },
  { city: 'c', value: 1, sector: 'Hardware' },
  { city: 'd', value: 1, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'e', value: 1, sector: 'Hospital' },
  { city: 'f', value: 1, sector: 'Education' },
  { city: 'g', value: 1, sector: 'Transport' },
  { city: 'h', value: 1, sector: 'Food' },
  { city: 'i', value: 1, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'j', value: 0.7, sector: 'Software' },
  { city: 'k', value: 0.7, sector: 'Education' },
  { city: 'l', value: 0.7, sector: 'Food' },
  { city: 'm', value: 0.7, sector: 'Hospital' },
  { city: 'n', value: 0.2, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'o', value: 0.2, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'p', value: 0.2, sector: 'Industrial' },
  { city: 'q', value: 0.2, sector: 'Transport' },
  { city: 'r', value: 0.2, sector: 'Software' } ]
```

Now i want to convert array of object into object with Array, city which have same repetition of sector should be comes under specific group.

Desired output be like this:

```
[
 {
  sector: "Hospital",
  place: ["a", "e", "m"]
 },
 {
  sector: "Hardware",
  place: ["b", "c"]
 },
 {
  sector: "Networking",
  place: ["d", "i", "n", "o"]
 },
 {
  sector: "Education",
  place: ["f", "k"]
 },
 {
  sector: "Transport",
  place: ["g", "q"]
 },
 {
  sector: "Food",
  place: ["h", "l"]
 },
 {
  sector: "Software",
  place: ["j", "r"]
 },
 {
  sector: "Industrial",
  place: ["q"]
 },
]
```

Is there any one who suggest me how to do this type of task.
Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

I have a clue that this things will be done through reduce and map function, but how that will be challenge.

I tried for getting the sector repetition count like this but not acheived with my desired outputs:

```
let x = data.reduce((m, c) => {
  if (c.sector in m) m[c.sector].count += 1;
   else m[c.sector] = { sector: c.sector, count: 1 };
   return m;
}, {});
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can first extract all `uniq` sectors in an `array`.

After that `map` into each sector and `filter` in your data which place correspond to.

```js
var data = [{ city: 'a', value: 1, sector: 'Hospital' },
  { city: 'b', value: 1, sector: 'Hardware' },
  { city: 'c', value: 1, sector: 'Hardware' },
  { city: 'd', value: 1, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'e', value: 1, sector: 'Hospital' },
  { city: 'f', value: 1, sector: 'Education' },
  { city: 'g', value: 1, sector: 'Transport' },
  { city: 'h', value: 1, sector: 'Food' },
  { city: 'i', value: 1, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'j', value: 0.7, sector: 'Software' },
  { city: 'k', value: 0.7, sector: 'Education' },
  { city: 'l', value: 0.7, sector: 'Food' },
  { city: 'm', value: 0.7, sector: 'Hospital' },
  { city: 'n', value: 0.2, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'o', value: 0.2, sector: 'Networking' },
  { city: 'p', value: 0.2, sector: 'Industrial' },
  { city: 'q', value: 0.2, sector: 'Transport' },
  { city: 'r', value: 0.2, sector: 'Software' } ];
  
  
  var sectors = [];
  
  data.map(d => {
    if(sectors.indexOf(d.sector) === -1){
       sectors.push(d.sector);
    }
  })
  
  sectors = sectors.map(sector => {
     return {
        sector,
        places:data.filter(d => d.sector === sector).map(d => d.city)
     }
  });
  
  console.log(sectors)
```

Comment: thanks buddy for suggesting me the easiest and best approach

Comment: Good solution @Alexis, you got my thumbs up, but take into consideration that this will be a little painful for big data sets (not this particular case)

Comment: `data.map(d => { ...` returns an array of undefined values, why not use `data.forEach` instead since you're doing nothing with the returned array. Or even better in my opinion, use `.reduce` - `var sectors = data.reduce((a, d) => {
    if (!a.includes(d.sector)) { a.push(d.sector); }
    return a;
  }, []);`

Comment: @Profit Agree with you but anyway if you don't use the returned data, you can use both map and forEach it have no impact.

Comment: Yes both work and this solution works nicely :) Just wanted to note that this usage of `map` is an anti-pattern and that `forEach` is the preferred method in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) slightly differently with [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). No need to create a separate array of keys this way.

```js
const data = [{"city":"a","value":1,"sector":"Hospital"},{"city":"b","value":1,"sector":"Hardware"},{"city":"c","value":1,"sector":"Hardware"},{"city":"d","value":1,"sector":"Networking"},{"city":"e","value":1,"sector":"Hospital"},{"city":"f","value":1,"sector":"Education"},{"city":"g","value":1,"sector":"Transport"},{"city":"h","value":1,"sector":"Food"},{"city":"i","value":1,"sector":"Networking"},{"city":"j","value":0.7,"sector":"Software"},{"city":"k","value":0.7,"sector":"Education"},{"city":"l","value":0.7,"sector":"Food"},{"city":"m","value":0.7,"sector":"Hospital"},{"city":"n","value":0.2,"sector":"Networking"},{"city":"o","value":0.2,"sector":"Networking"},{"city":"p","value":0.2,"sector":"Industrial"},{"city":"q","value":0.2,"sector":"Transport"},{"city":"r","value":0.2,"sector":"Software"}];
  
const out = data.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Grab the sector and city
  const { sector, city } = c;

  // Find an object in the array that matches the sector
  const found = acc.findIndex(el => el.sector === sector);

  // If it exists...
  if (found > -1) {

    // ...push a new city to the place array
    acc[found].place.push(city);
  } else {

    // ...otherwise push a new object to the array
    // with the starter city
    acc.push({ sector, place: [city] });
  }

  return acc;

}, []);

console.log(out);
```

Comment: A clean, self-contained solution. I learned something new today, thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will iterate using `reduce` over the array and store the unique sectors in an array and then return an array using `map` and `filter` with the required values.

```
function normalize (input){
  const sectors = input.reduce(function(result, value){
    if(result.indexOf(value.sector) === -1){
      result.push(value.sector);
    }  
    return result;
  }, []);

  return sectors.map(function(sector){
    return {
      sector,
      places: input.filter(function(entry){
        return entry.sector === sector;
      }).map(function(entry){
        return entry.city;
      })
    }
  });
}
```